# What is the meaning of <rayCount>, <rangeCount> and <laserCount> for laser sensor XML?

Tags: gazebo-sensor

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, I am using simulating a laser sensor. However, I have some doubts about the meaning of some tags in the xml description. Even the ROS web page do not provide information on this. Can anyone explain what is the meaning of the above mentioned tag? Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/563/what-is-the-meaning-of-%3Craycount%3E,-%3Crangecount%3E-and-%3Clasercount%3E-for-laser-sensor-xml?/) by [ChengXiang](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/54/chengxiang/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2012-12-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

`<rangeCount>` is the number of data values you want to produce.  `<rayCount>` is the number of simulated rays in the physics engine.  If `<rayCount>` is smaller than `<rangeCount>`, then some range values will be produced by interpolation (you might do this to reduce CPU usage).

I don't know what `<laserCount>` does; I don't think that it's a valid tag.

Btw, you're apparently using a pretty old version of Gazebo, as these tags are from the pre-SDF-1.0 world file format.  You should consider upgrading.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChengXiang](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/54/chengxiang/) on 2013-01-19**:
Thanks for clarifying. I am using version 1.6.16 simulator_gazebo with ROS, is that consider old?